# Parse Cloud Code save() doesn't seem to save a field

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to run save() on a retrieved _User object, but it doesn't seems to save the field I've modified ("ignoredUsers"), which is an array. Although I can see that the save actually went through, as updatedAt does change.

Here is the code:

```
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.equalTo("objectId", userid1);
    query.first({
      success: function(result){
        var ignored = result.get("ignoredUsers");
        if (!ignored) {
          ignored = [];
        }
        ignored.push(userid2);
        result.set("ignoredUsers", ignored);
        result.save();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function appendUser(toUser, userId) {
  return toUser.fetch({
    success: function(user) {
      var ignored = user.get("ignoredUsers");
      if (!ignored) {
        ignored = [];
      }
      ignored.push(userId);
      user.set("ignoredUsers", ignored);
      user.save();
    }
  });
}

Parse.Cloud.job("ignoredUsers", function(request, status) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var query = new Parse.Query("Conversation");
  return query.each(function(conversation) {
    var participants = conversation.get("participants");
    var userid1 = participants[0].id;
    var userid2 = participants[1].id;
    var user1 = participants[0];
    var user2 = participants[1];
    return appendUser(user1, userid2).then(function() {
      return appendUser(user2, userid1); });
  });
  status.success();
});
```

The problem was that the cloud function returned before waiting for the callbacks to finish